# Is Wikipidia wrong about Schnorr Signatures?

Tags: schnorr-signature

Wikipidia says [Schnorr signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature) generation is defined like this:

```
Y = x * G //this is the key we are trying to provide a signature for
k = random scalar
r = k * G
e = Hash_to_scalar(r || message)
s = k - xe
signature = (s, e)
```

This seems correct, but then to verify it's defined as:

```
r = s * G * e * Y
e = Hash_to_scalar(r || message)
```

Shouldn't it be:

```
r = s * G + e * Y
e = Hash_to_scalar(r || message)
```

because:

```
r = k - xe * G + ex * G == k * G; //this works
r = k - xe * G * ex * G != k * G; //this doesnt work
```

Or have I made a silly mistake somewhere?

Comment: Why should $k - xe + ex * G$ be equal to $k * G$ ?

Comment: Ah i made a typo. i mean k - xe * G + ex * G. edited now

Comment: Since Wikipedia pages evolve, it is a good idea to look at the version history to find the [version that you probably looked at](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Schnorr_signature&oldid=865587129), rather than the most recent version.

Answer (score 3):

The equation in Wikipedia is `r = s*G + e*Y`, and not `r = s*G * e*Y`

Thus, `r = s*G + e*Y = (k - xe)*G + e*(x*G) = k*G - xe*G + xe*G = k*G`

Comment: In fact, the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnorr_signature) is also completely wrong since it keeps mixing additive and multiplicative notations.

Comment: I have fixed the Wikipedia page.

Comment: @Conrado yes that was an edit made by me. Previously it said r =  s * G * e * Y but i edited it to see if a moderator would remove correct me in case i was wrong :)

Comment: @Thomas Pornin: useful fix! But the signature scheme as originally described differs slightly: the signature is $\left(H\left(g^k\mathbin\|M\right), k+x\,H\left(g^k\mathbin\|M\right)\right)$ with the hash much shorter than $q$; also notice the $+$ (Claus-Peter Schnorr described both as features). Detailed description of the original scheme and bibliography [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/48528/555). Practice often differs, especially for Elliptic Curve variants, taxonomy [there](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50202/555).

Comment: @ fgrieu Thank you for documenting Schnorr signature scheme and further development.