# How to encrypt using private key for ECC

Tags: encryption, elliptic-curves, signature, message-recovery

As we know, ECC using $C_2 = r \cdot G, C_1 = M + r \cdot G$; and decrypt with $M=C_1 - K \cdot C_2$. And sign using point $X$:
$X = k \cdot G(x_0,y_0)$. $r = x_0 \cdot K; s = 1 / k \cdot (M + r \cdot d) \mod(n)$; here $d$ is  private key, $K$ is public  key.
and then verify by is true of $r \cdot G == M \cdot G / s + x \cdot K/s$.

Here is my question: can I encrypt using private key (or sign) and get the message $M$ directly by public key $K$? Instead of $r \cdot G == M \cdot G / s + x \cdot K/s$, how can I got something like $M = \operatorname{function}(r,s,K,G)$ ?

Thanks
Edward

Comment: Actually, the standard method to encrypt using ECC is [ECIES](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.5.1). Standard methods to sign using ECC include [ECDSA](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf#subsection.4.1) and [EC-Schnorr](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/34863/555).

Comment: Err, why do you want to encrypt with your private key. Since your public key is public implies the encrypted message can decrypt by everybody. What is your actual problem? Also, private key is integer and public key is a point!

Comment: I try to replace RSA with ECC in a very small project. If ECC can't do that, I may still use RSA to do that message recovery.

Comment: If you cannot live with the 64 byte overhead of ECC (assuming 256 bit key size) then I would recommend sticking with RSA, although it is less strong in the classical sense and that signatures giving message recovery are generally not state-of-the-art like PSS.

Answer (score 5):

In public-key cryptography, there is **NO SUCH THING** as "encrypt with private key". It's a misnomer since the RSA days.

Also, what you describe as "M = function(pubkey, signature)" is signature with message recovery. These algorithms are rare nowadays and had been largely replaced with signature with appendix (which ECDSA is one of them).

ECC as specified in SEC#* series of standards are based on discrete logarithm problem over elliptic curves. By their nature, building DLog-based trapdoor permutation of arbitrary size is significantly more inefficient than building signature formula that use DLog difficulty to prevent secret components from leaking. Therefore, ECC don't have digital signature with message recovery.

Comment: In the case that we don't need to know the message before we verify the signature. If we can calculate M=function(pubkey,signature), we can directly get M and verified. RSA can do that, why ECC can't?  --- regardless of why we need this , could you please tell how to solve this M=func(pub,sign) in ECC ?

Comment: @Edward See if that's a satisfactory explanation.

Comment: It is great to know that ECC can't do message recovery. and I agree with you about the efficiency issue. Yet, it is true that there are some cases that we need message recovery. First is that hash can be made ,though it is difficult.  Verified hash  don't 100%ly means message is the true Message.  In my another case, we need message recovery.