# How or in which format should Schnorr signature keys be stored?

Tags: pki, schnorr-signature

I would like to know if there is any standard for storing public and private keys for Schnorr signature

Comment: There are many variants of Schnorr signatures, on different kinds of groups; see e.g. [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/34863/555). Does the context specify something, like the group used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is none. Schnorr's signature had only ever been academically described, so <s>no standard for it</s> there is all variaty of potentially incompatible specifications for it, lacking a *uniform* standard. There was standard for ElGamel encryption when NIST was running the OSI Implementor's Workshop, but it wasn't widely used.

There is however, EdDSA, which is a composition of Edwards elliptic curve with Schnorr's signature. It's specified in [RFC-8032](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8032).

Of course, lacking a uniform standard doesn't prevent us from storing private key as big-endian integers and public keys as big-endian integers or elliptic curve points. All you need is to choose an existing standard (e.g. [PKCS#3](https://www.teletrust.de/fileadmin/files/oid/oid_pkcs-3v1-4.pdf), [SEC#1](https://www.secg.org/sec1-v2.pdf), IEEE-1363, ISO/IEC-14888-3, etc.) and apply its encoding to the academic version of Schnorr.

Comment: Can't agree with "no standard for it". There are too many! For example; [ISO/IEC 14888-3](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/en/#!iso:std:76382:en) standardizes "Elliptic Curve Schnorr Digital Signature Algorithm" as EC-SDSA \[OID [1.0.14888.3.0.11](http://oid-info.com/get/1.0.14888.3.0.11)\] with variant EC-SDSA-opt \[OID [1.0.14888.3.0.13](http://oid-info.com/get/1.0.14888.3.0.13)\], and EC-FSDSA \[OID [1.0.14888.3.0.12](http://oid-info.com/get/1.0.14888.3.0.12)\]. EC-SDSA-opt is endorsed by ETSI, and BSI also an ECSDSA (with a fix). I was told one of these is used in a Smart Card application.

Comment: @fgrieu Is my new wording acceptable?

Comment: Ok, but i would like to know if there is any known way to save and store the Schnorr keys like you would do with ECDSA's or RSA's

Comment: @RazvanMarian Added a paragraph for you.